# How to avoid chaining OR conditions with `|`?

Tags: r, subset

How can I avoid chaining OR conditions with `|` like this:

```
small_town_villages = data_ger[which(data_ger$type_city==1|data_ger$type_city==2 |data_ger$type_city==3),]

city = data_ger[~(small_town_villages),]
```

Is their a way of doing this more concisely? Furthermore, I think there is an error in my last line.

Comment: `data_ger$type_city %in% 1:3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `%in%`:

```
small_town_villages = data_ger[data_ger$type_city %in% c(1:3),]
```

or `!x %in% y` if you want the list of not included values.